# Let $A \in M(n, \mathbb{R})$. Prove that for every matrix $A$ exists a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{R}[X]$, such that $f(A) = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $A \in M(n, \mathbb{R})$ ($n$x$n$ matrix under $\mathbb{R}$). Prove that for every matrix $A$ exists a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{R}[X]$, such that $f(A) = 0$.

Where, $f(A) = a_nA^n + ... + a_1A + a_0E_n$.

I tried to use [Polynomial remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem), but no more idea.

Comment: Cf. [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)

Comment: What about the polynomial $0$?

Comment: To prove that there is a (nozero!) polynomial $f$ of degree at most $n^2$ such that $f(A)=0$ is fairly trivial: $I, A, A^2,\ldots, A^{n^2}$ are $n^2+1$ matrices in a $n^2$-dimensional vector space $M_n(\mathbb R)$ - and so they must be linearly dependent. To prove that the degree of $f$ can be chosen to be $\le n$ is a lot harder and normally is taken as a consequence of Cayley-Hamilton theorem. (Spoiler: take $f(x)=\det(A-xI)$, and degree of $f$ is $n$ because of the way how the determinant is calculated.)

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid Cayley-Hamilton with the structure theorem for finitely-generated modules over a PID.

By the structure theorem, we have
$$\mathbb R^n=\bigoplus_{i=1}^m\mathbb R[x]/(f_i).$$
Now take $f=\prod_{i=1}^mf_i$, then $f$ acts by $0$ on $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. $f(A)=0$. Comparing dimensions tells us that
$$n=\dim\mathbb R^n=\sum_{i=1}^m\dim\mathbb R[x]/(f_i)=\sum_{i=1}^m\deg f_i=\deg f.$$

---

Here's a neat method to show that some polynomial must annihilate $A$.

Suppose not. Then $I,A,\dots,A^{n^2-1}$ are linearly independent, so form a basis for $M_n(\mathbb R)$.

Hence every matrix commutes with $A$, so $A=\lambda I$. Then take $f(x)=x-\lambda$ for a contradiction.

Comment: It seems that the OP wants to prove that the degree of the polynomial is $\le n$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop good point -- I need to learn to read. I've edited in a proof via the PID structure theorem